# Building multi-stage docker images with ansible

Tags: docker, ansible

I have a multi-stage dockerfile with the target `prod_image`, which I can build from the command line using the `--target` flag, eg:

```
docker build --target prod_image .
```

My ansible yml looks like this:

```
tasks:
 - name: Build image and push to Docker Hub
   docker_image:
     dockerfile: 'Dockerfile'
     target: prod_image  
     name: "my_docker_name"
     repository: "my_private_repo"
     tag: "1.1.0"
     state: present
    push: yes
```

Here is the error message I get:
`{"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (docker_image) module: target Supported parameters include...`

Any ideas on how I can fix this.

Answer (score 0):

[Ansible docker_image](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_image_module.html) module doesn't support `target` parameter.

You need to modify your Dockerfile, so last stage there will be `prod_image` = you won't need the target parameter for docker build command.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. To clarify my build stages are:
1) Build
2) Test
3) Create Prod (this is essentially just the Build stage without any test config)

In my pipeline I have build and test as step 1. then upload to prod in step 2. I don't want it to run tests again in step 2. By using --target it doesn't. Without it it does.